# Understanding and trying to use Valgrind for C programming.

Tags: c

I am following  a tutorial [From Here](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex4.html)

This is the program I am trying to run:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
int age=10; 
int height; 

printf("The age is %d \n"); 
printf("The height is %d \n", height);

return 0; 

}
```

`Please note the errors are self induced to check on functionality`

Then from the command line:
$ make ex3
vlagrind ./ex3

I get the output:

```
==6771== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6771== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6771== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6771== Command: ./ex3
==6771== 
The age is -16776936 
==6771== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6771==    at 0x4E7C4F1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6771==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6771==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
==6771== 
==6771== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==6771==    at 0x4E7A7EB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==6771==    by 0x4E7C837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6771==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6771==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
==6771== 
==6771== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6771==    at 0x4E7A7F5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==6771==    by 0x4E7C837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6771==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6771==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
==6771== 
The height is 0 
==6771== 
==6771== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6771==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6771==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==6771== 
==6771== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6771== 
==6771== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6771== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==6771== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
junaid@pc-dev-a147:~/Desktop/C folder$ valgrind --track-origins=yes ./ex3
==6788== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6788== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6788== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6788== Command: ./ex3
==6788== 
The age is -16776936 
==6788== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6788==    at 0x4E7C4F1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6788==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6788==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
==6788==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==6788==    at 0x4004F4: main (ex3.c:2)
==6788== 
==6788== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==6788==    at 0x4E7A7EB: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==6788==    by 0x4E7C837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6788==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6788==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
==6788==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==6788==    at 0x4004F4: main (ex3.c:2)
==6788== 
==6788== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6788==    at 0x4E7A7F5: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:195)
==6788==    by 0x4E7C837: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6788==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6788==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
==6788==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==6788==    at 0x4004F4: main (ex3.c:2)
==6788== 
The height is 0 
==6788== 
==6788== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6788==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6788==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==6788== 
==6788== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6788== 
==6788== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6788== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

I am not able to make anything out of it, while as the tutorial tells me that I will get line numbers at which the error has occurred. How to read the Valgrind output?

Comment: You get a stack trace for every problem and a reference to the site of creation of the problematic variable, how can you ask for better reporting? =)

Comment: Yes true that, but I want to make sense out of what it displays, am new to Valgrind and learning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the last line here:

```
The age is -16776936 
==6771== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==6771==    at 0x4E7C4F1: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1629)
==6771==    by 0x4E858D8: printf (printf.c:35)
==6771==    by 0x40052B: main (ex3.c:7)
```

This is telling you the function (`main`), the file (`ex3.c`) and the line number (`7`) to review.

The `by 0xXYZ` entries are memory addresses of caller functions, at each step of the stack backtrace. This is probably less useful to you than the line number and error message.

Repeat this parsing step for other errors.

Comment: Okay the count of lines starts from the import statements itself? It also takes into consideration blank lines/ or whitespaces? Also do I always have to concentrate on the last part of the valgrind output?

Comment: The line numbers as always are from the start of the file, and count every line (including empty ones). You are provided stack traces, so for each problem on the top is the location where the problem arises (in this case inside the implementation of vfprintf), followed by the nested function calls that brought you there. Typically you'll want to start examining the stack trace where it starts to refer to code you wrote yourself (in this case, where it starts to mention ex3.c).

Comment: But why is it pointing at line 7 for the uninitialized value? `height` is uninitialized and the program tried to print it at line 8. Bug in the tool?

Comment: No I think the tool does not detect if a value is initialized or not, it does so when it is working with that variable, like printing it.

Comment: Also would be great if you explain what does the `by 0x40052B` reflect in the above context?

Comment: This is the memory address of the caller function, for each step in the  stack backtrace.

Comment: Thank you, seems the tool is much more powerful than I assumed!